# How much weaker do PETG parts become when exposed to UV light from the sun?

Tags: petg, material, print-strength

What is the effect of UV on PETG parts? Can I minimize that effect by placing some kind of UV light blocking film/coating?

Also, is there a limit in how much weaker a part can become because of exposure to UV light?

Comment: Have you done any initial research on this? General knowledge is that PETG is not heavily affected by UV, although the pigments used to color it may be. I'm not sure how to quantify "how much". Are you looking for quantitative part strength tests (like the kind CNC Kitchen does) comparing a part exposed to UV for N years vs a newly printed part? I imagine that will be hard to find.

Comment: Yes I have. There aren't any numbers out there

Comment: Well then are you looking for anecdotal info?